$\alpha$ stable processes without jumps
Levy processes with jumps can be formulated following the Levy-kinchkine representation, which provide a decomposition of the characteristic function into three factors corresponding to the diffusion (continuous part), the drift and the jumps (expressed as an integral involving the Levy measures).
Is it possible to formulate a stochastic process without jumps but still with fat tailed distribution?
In other words can we have a process, which similarly to the gaussian case allow the continuous limit (and where each variation is the result of incremental variations on smaller time scales) but ruled by a fat tailed noise distribution (alpha stable)?
if yes:

is it known the probability distribution (or at least its characteristic function)?
can we compute the drift term of the reverse SDE, where the forward SDE follows:

$x_{t+dt} -x_t = b(x,t) dt + dL^{\alpha}$
, while the reverse SDE follows:
$x_t - x_{t+dt}= \tilde{b}(x,t) dt + dL^{\alpha}$

What about (say) the constant (in time) process $X_t=X$, where $X$ has a stable law?
